# AS3 - Longest data types needed

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a long data type. Using Number and Uint usually stops me at 4.2 billion. Any way I can have a really really long data type? And I need full integers, not decimals(API only accepts integers). I cannot find anything anywhere. Adobe says Number is extremely large (1.7*10E308) but at 4.2 bil, it always resets to 0...

Any idea?

Looks like this right now:

```
var gold:Number=0;

var highscoregold:uint=0; 

highscoregold=gold;

gold_txt.text= ""+gold;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is native "big integer" type in Action Script and related libraries.

There are some external libraries that implement type (usually called `BigInteger` as Java counterpart) you are looking for. I.e. some random links found by searching for [actionscript biginteger](http://www.bing.com/search?q=actionscript+biginteger):  [As3 BigInteger returns an Incorrect Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469829/as3-biginteger-returns-an-incorrect-answer) or http://www.granitedataservices.com/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.bignumbers.html

Comment: How do you import an external library? Do you just need to code "import stuff stuff", or do you need extra files? I'm a total beginner.

Comment: http://www.granitedataservices.com/public/doc/2.2.0/doc/as3/api/org/granite/math/BigInteger.html I'm at that page and I don't know what to download... :/ Can you give a more detailed explanation? ^^

Comment: @user3105028 - I don't know - I've never needed this type in my (very short) period of using AS. I've just searched to see if there is this type avaialbe... I'm not sure, but according to http://www.graniteddataservices.com site all open sources are on GITHub under https://github.com/graniteds/ . You may have better luck to search for "ActionScript BigInteger" in your favorite search engine and try other links.

Comment: Thank you =) I found out that my problem is not the one I thought. The number gets converted to a uint when being displayed, regardless of what goes on before. I need to change my display settings, cheers!

Comment: @user3105028 - glad you solved your problem. Side note: as far as I remember numbers outside of normal `int` range stored internally as `float`/`double` - so while range is huge precisions is not. If you need something precise like "high score in billions points" you still need integer values of some kind and `Number` will not work.